# al editar un formulario mantener seleccionado la opción del select según el valor que existe en la bd

Tags: php

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="e_f_p">Escuela de Fromacion Profesional</label>
            <select name="e_f_p" id="e_f_p" class="form-control">
                <option value="DERECHO" >DERECHO</option>   
                <option value="INGENIERÍA">INGENIERÍA</option>
                <option value="ADMINISTRACIÓN">ADMINISTRACIÓ</option>
            </select>                   
        </div>      
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">

   <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
            <input type="text" name="nombre" required value="{{$formulario->nombre}}" class="form-control">     
        </div>      
    </div>
```

Comment: ¿Y cómo se determina el valor que existe en la base de datos? Pulsa aquí: [edit]  para editar la pregunta y dar los detalles que faltan. Gracias.

Comment: ¿Estás usando laravel? sino indicanos cuál es.

Comment: agrega mas detalles como que framework estas usando..!!

Comment: si disculpen por no ser muy claro estoy usando laravel 5.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debido a que estas usando laravel, supongo que esta vista es la de editar y ya tienes una objeto con el atributo seleccionado...

Supongamos que tienes esto 
$registro->nombre
$formulario->profesion

La forma correcta de hacerlo seria

```html
<select name="e_f_p" id="e_f_p" class="form-control">
   <option value="DERECHO" {{ ($formulario->profesion == 'DERECHO') ? 'selected':'' }}>DERECHO</option>   
   <option value="INGENIERÍA" {{ ($formulario->profesion == 'INGENIERÍA') ? 'selected':''}} >INGENIERÍA</option>
   <option value="ADMINISTRACIÓN" {{ ($formulario->profesion == 'ADMINISTRACIÓN') ? 'selected':''}}>ADMINISTRACIÓ</option>
</select>
```

Espero te sirva, esto igual lo puedes mejorar haciendo que las opciones vengan desde una base de datos y recorriendo estos registros.

Saludos

Comment: muchas gracias Gerardo Pacheco era justo lo que necesitaba enserio muchísimas gracias